# Swagger: Failed to load API definition. Fetch errorFailed to fetch openconfig-interfaces.yaml

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-ui

Below is my files:
[image]
It works fine when opening index.html
[image]

Error when clicking openconfig-interfaces
[image]

error details:

```
{"schemaValidationMessages":[{"level":"error","message":"Can't read from file file://tt/rest_ui/openconfig-interfaces.yaml"}]}
```

Actually the file openconfig-interfaces.yaml is there.
Any suggestion to solve this problem, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a cross domain issue, Install the live server plugin in vscode, and then open it again